# HTml5 video playsinline muted: how to unmute?

Tags: html, html5-video

On IOS, 
I want to use inline video so I use

```
<video controls  webkit-playsinline  playsinline autoplay ..>
```

That works fine: **video auto starts inline on iphone muted.**

But how can I unmute it (inclduing manually by clicking a volume button: the player has no mute button)